# pandas.groupby.nsmallest drops multiindex when dataframe is presorted

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas (0.22.0, python version 3.6.4) `.groupby` with the `.nsmallest` method to find the smallest items in each group of a dataframe. Here is an example dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
                             'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar',
                             'qux', 'qux', 'qux'],
                       'b': ['baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'bat',
                             'baz', 'baz', 'bat', 'bat', 'bat',
                             'baz', 'bat', 'bat'],
                       'c': [1, 3, 2, 5,
                             6, 4, 9, 12, 7,
                             10, 8, 11]})
```

I want the three smallest values in column 'c' for each 'a'/'b' pair. The expression I am using to get the n-smallest values for each group in the 'c' column is as follows:

```
>>> (df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3))
     .reset_index(level=['a', 'b']))
```

This returns the following data frame, as expected:

```
      a    b   c
8   bar  bat   7
6   bar  bat   9
7   bar  bat  12
5   bar  baz   4
4   bar  baz   6
3   foo  bat   5
0   foo  baz   1
2   foo  baz   2
1   foo  baz   3
10  qux  bat   8
11  qux  bat  11
9   qux  baz  10
```

But a strange thing happens if the data frame is sorted from smallest to largest on column 'c' first:

```
>>> df2 = df.sort_values('c', ascending=True)
>>> (df2.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3))
     .reset_index(level=['a', 'b']))
```

This returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-2afabcab898a> in <module>()
      1 (df2.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3))
----> 2          .reset_index(level=['a', 'b']))
      3

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, name, inplace)
   1048         else:
   1049             df = self.to_frame(name)
-> 1050             return df.reset_index(level=level, drop=drop)
   1051
   1052     def __unicode__(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, inplace, col_level, col_fill)
   3339             if not isinstance(level, (tuple, list)):
   3340                 level = [level]
-> 3341             level = [self.index._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level]
   3342             if isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
   3343                 if len(level) < self.index.nlevels:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   3339             if not isinstance(level, (tuple, list)):
   3340                 level = [level]
-> 3341             level = [self.index._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level]
   3342             if isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
   3343                 if len(level) < self.index.nlevels:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _get_level_number(self, level)
   1618
   1619     def _get_level_number(self, level):
-> 1620         self._validate_index_level(level)
   1621         return 0
   1622

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _validate_index_level(self, level)
   1615         elif level != self.name:
   1616             raise KeyError('Level %s must be same as name (%s)' %
-> 1617                            (level, self.name))
   1618
   1619     def _get_level_number(self, level):

KeyError: 'Level a must be same as name (None)'
```

Clearly, the `.reset_index` is the problem, so we'll remove that:

```
>>> df2.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3))
```

And we get back this series:

```
0      1
2      2
1      3
5      4
3      5
4      6
8      7
10     8
6      9
9     10
11    11
7     12
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Removing `reset_index` from the first example shows the MultiIndex:

```
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3))
a    b
bar  bat  8      7
          6      9
          7     12
     baz  5      4
          4      6
foo  bat  3      5
     baz  0      1
          2      2
          1      3
qux  bat  10     8
          11    11
     baz  9     10
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

So something about the dataframe being sorted caused the MultiIndex from the `groupby` operation to to drop out. The same happens if we sort from largest to smallest and call `nlargest`:

```
>>> df3 = df.sort_values('c', ascending=False)
>>> df3.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3))
7     12
11    11
9     10
6      9
10     8
8      7
4      6
3      5
5      4
1      3
2      2
0      1
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

And the same thing even happens if we try to get crafty with a negative sign:

```
>>> df3.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: (-x).nsmallest(3))
7    -12
11   -11
9    -10
6     -9
10    -8
8     -7
4     -6
3     -5
5     -4
1     -3
2     -2
0     -1
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

But not if we use `nlargest` with the negative sign:

```
>>> df3.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: (-x).nlargest(3))
a    b
bar  bat  8     -7
          6     -9
          7    -12
     baz  5     -4
          4     -6
foo  bat  3     -5
     baz  0     -1
          2     -2
          1     -3
qux  bat  10    -8
          11   -11
     baz  9    -10
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

I have played around with this a lot, and I'm pretty stumped. You may ask "Why sort the data frame if you know it will cause this error?", but this happens with `nsmallest` if even one of the groups happens to be sorted ascending, and with `nlargest` if a group is sorted descending. Here is a quick example:

```
>>> df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
                        'b': ['baz', 'baz', 'bat', 'baz', 'bat'],
                        'c': [1, 2, 10, 4, 7]})
     a    b   c
0  foo  baz   1
1  foo  baz   2
2  foo  bat  10
3  bar  baz   4
4  bar  bat   7

>>> df4.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3))
0     1
1     2
2    10
3     4
4     7
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Is this behavior expected, or is it a bug in pandas? Can anyone recommend a solution to the error? Right now I am simply defensively sorting the data frame in the opposite direction before using `groupby` and `nsmallest`:

```
>>> df5 = df4.sort_values('c', ascending=False)
>>> (df5.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(3))
     .reset_index(level=['a', 'b']))
     a    b   c
4  bar  bat   7
3  bar  baz   4
2  foo  bat  10
0  foo  baz   1
1  foo  baz   2
```

But this seems unnecessary and messy. Any ideas or insights are greatly appreciated!

**Edit 06/18/18:**
After looking at the links @gyoza suggested, I understand that the problem is not with `nsmallest` or `nlargest`, rather with the results of the `apply` operation on the groupby object. If the Series returned by the `apply` operation has the same index as the original groupby group, pandas returns the original index rather than the multiIndex.

@gyoza's solution creates a Series in the apply operation with a new index to ensure that the multiIndex is returned. In my actual code, however, a later step (which marks the smallest in each group for review) depends on the original index being preserved through the apply operation. I could rewrite that step as a merge on the grouping columns rather than indexing with `.loc`, but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, "bug" I think you found here in pandas.SeriesGroupBy object with sorted dataframes.

I think instead we a can use pandas.DataFrameGroupBy object (however, I do believe you have a bug there).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
                             'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar',
                             'qux', 'qux', 'qux'],
                       'b': ['baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'bat',
                             'baz', 'baz', 'bat', 'bat', 'bat',
                             'baz', 'bat', 'bat'],
                       'c': [1, 3, 2, 5,
                             6, 4, 9, 12, 7,
                             10, 8, 11]})

df2 = df.sort_values('c', ascending=True)

df_sorted = df2.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(n=3, columns='c')).reset_index(drop=True)

df_unsorted = df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(n=3, columns='c')).reset_index(drop=True)

all(df_sorted.eqw(df_unsorted)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Print df_sorted and df_unsorted:

```
print(df_sorted)

      a    b   c
0   bar  bat   7
1   bar  bat   9
2   bar  bat  12
3   bar  baz   4
4   bar  baz   6
5   foo  bat   5
6   foo  baz   1
7   foo  baz   2
8   foo  baz   3
9   qux  bat   8
10  qux  bat  11
11  qux  baz  10
```

print(df_unsorted)

```
      a    b   c
0   bar  bat   7
1   bar  bat   9
2   bar  bat  12
3   bar  baz   4
4   bar  baz   6
5   foo  bat   5
6   foo  baz   1
7   foo  baz   2
8   foo  baz   3
9   qux  bat   8
10  qux  bat  11
11  qux  baz  10
```

Comment: @DSM  Can you comment, I think you'll have worked on multiindex problems in the past.