# Pandas: Take rolling sum of next (1 ... n) rows of a column within a group and create a new column for each sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataframe :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x1 = ['j','j','j','k','k','k','k','k']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a,'b':x1})  

print(df)

a   b
1   j
2   j
3   j
4   k
5   k
6   k
7   k
8   k
```

I am trying get the sum the "a" values for next n rows grouped within column "b" and store it in new columns (for n ranging from 1 to 4).

Essentially I want to end up with four new columns c1, c2, c3, and c4 such that c1 has sum of "next 1" a's, c2 has sum of "next 2" a's, c3 has sum of "next 3" a's and c4 has sum of "next 4" a's.

Therefore, my desired output is:

```
a   b   c1      c2      c3      c4  
1   j   2.0     5.0     NaN     NaN
2   j   3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   j   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   k   5.0     11.0    18.0    26.0
5   k   6.0     13.0    21.0    NaN
6   k   7.0     15.0    NaN     NaN
7   k   8.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   k   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I looked for solutions and best I can think of is something like:

```
for x in range(1,5): 
    df[x] = df.groupby(['b'])a[::-1].rolling(x+1).sum()[::-1] - a
```

but this syntax throws errors.

If possible, can you also share how to implement if I need to group by more than one fields. Will really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example dataframe doesn't match your expected output, so let's go with the latter.

I think you can combine a rolling sum with a shift:

```
for x in range(1, 5):
    c = pd.Series(df.groupby("b")["a"].rolling(x).sum().values, index=df.index)
    df[f"c{x}"]= c.groupby(df["b"]).shift(-x)
```

gives me

```
In [302]: df
Out[302]: 
   a  b   c1    c2    c3    c4
0  1  j  2.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
1  2  j  3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  3  j  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  4  k  5.0  11.0  18.0  26.0
4  5  k  6.0  13.0  21.0   NaN
5  6  k  7.0  15.0   NaN   NaN
6  7  k  8.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  8  k  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

If you really want to have multiple keys, you can use a list of keys, but we have to rearrange the call a little:

```
keys = ["b","b2"]
for x in range(1, 5):
    c = pd.Series(df.groupby(keys)["a"].rolling(x).sum().values, index=df.index)
    df[f"c{x}"]= c.groupby([df[k] for k in keys]).shift(-x)
```

or

```
keys = ["b","b2"]
for x in range(1, 5):
    c = pd.Series(df.groupby(keys)["a"].rolling(x).sum().values, index=df.index)
    df[f"c{x}"]= df.assign(tmp=c).groupby(keys)["tmp"].shift(-x)
```

give me

```
In [409]: df
Out[409]: 
   a  b b2   c1    c2  c3  c4
0  1  j  j  2.0   5.0 NaN NaN
1  2  j  j  3.0   NaN NaN NaN
2  3  j  j  NaN   NaN NaN NaN
3  4  k  k  5.0   NaN NaN NaN
4  5  k  k  NaN   NaN NaN NaN
5  6  k  l  7.0  15.0 NaN NaN
6  7  k  l  8.0   NaN NaN NaN
7  8  k  l  NaN   NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @DSM. I updated the question as you pointed out. Your approach also works well so far. Only question is how can I apply it if I had to group by (say) 2 fields instead of one (b here)? For e.g. if the two grouping fields were b, p and I still wanted to sum a the same way to generate c's. Really appreciate your response.

Comment: Nevermind @DSM. I concatenated the fields in my data into one field, sorted them and was able to achieve the same

Comment: @DSM Would you take a look at this pandas multiindex potential bug?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574587/6361531